# Finding the intersection of $f(x)= x^4 - x^3 + 1$ and $g(x)= x^4 -2x^3 + x + 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to find the intersection of two lines

$$f(x)= x^4 - x^3 + 1$$ 
    and $$g(x)= x^4 -2x^3 + x + 1$$

I know the intersection points already $(0, 1)$ and $(1, 1)$, however I am not sure how to find the intersection points, algebraically, for functions of this order. How do I show this?

Comment: What about $(-1,3)$?

Comment: Title says "line and curve" and question says "two lines"; I would call them both curves, though some say curved lines

Comment: How do you know that those are the intersection points?

Comment: Yes I was unsure how to label them myself. I would probably go with curves. Technically though, in the real world they are still lines, albeit curved lines.

Comment: @amd I graphed it.

Comment: When I look at the graphs, I see three intersections, not two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't always do that. We want to find $x$ such that $f(x)=g(x)$ in this case

$x^4-x^3+1=x^4-2x^3+x+1$

In this case we can subtract $x^4$ from both  sides and rearranging we get

$x^3-x=0$

this can be solved using the [cubic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation), or by simpy factoring:

$x(x^2-1)=0$

And you find three solutions: $x=0$, $x=\pm 1$.

In general if you have a polynomial up to the order 4 there is a [general formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots), but you can't solve it for two generic polynomials because of the [Abel-Ruffini theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem)

Comment: Why $-1$? That term is cancelling, since it appears on both sides.

Comment: and Abel-Ruffini theorem refers to polynomial equations of degree five or higher, which these are not

Comment: @Andrei Yes it does, my bad, I corrected it

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Surely, if we have a order 3 polynomyal there's a general formula which I linked, but there's no solution for a generic polynomial, I reworded the answer to be more clear

Answer (score 2):

Set $x^4-x^3+1=x^4-2x^3+x+1$.

Then $x^3-x=0$.

Can you take it from here, or do you need further assistance?

Comment: Thank you. Yes I did need further assistance, but the comment below cleared it up. It is very obvious now to the point that I feel silly. It's been a long time for me since I've done maths.

Answer (score 2):

You have at the intersection $f(x)=g(x)$, or $$x^4-x^3+1=x^4-2x^3+x+1$$
Moving everything to one side:
$$x^3-x=0$$or $$x(x+1)(x-1)=0$$

Comment: Oh!!! Okay now I understand. Yes thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Solve the equation $f(x) = g(x)$. You will get three values of x: 0, 1 and -1. Corresponding points you will get as (0, 1), (1, 1) and (-1, 3) respectively.

Comment: did you mean *three* values of $x$?

Comment: Yes..my bad. I corrected it.